# Using Curl need to call a REST API

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying to generate a file using REST API by Header authorization "Bearer Token" and password encryption.

```sh
token=$(curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "aesiv: xxxxxxxx" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"login":"username","password":"encrypted_pswd"}' \
  https://ssssss/api/login)
```

```
curl -X GET https://ssssss/api/generate-report -H "Accept: encryptionIntVeD" "Authorization: aesiv {xxxxxxxxxxx}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
```

File not getting generated, can anyone guide me where I am stuck.

Comment: Assuming this is parts of a shell script, then it looks like you forgot a $ in front of {token}

Comment: Hi Team, 

Following error which i have received -       
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `-H` in front of "Authorization"

Comment: yeah, i have $ in front of {token} & -H in front of "Authorization".

Getting the following error:

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please update your question with the correct commands. And include the response when you do curl with a `-v`

Comment: The below line which i used:
curl -X GET https://sss/notifications/api/generate-report -H "Accept: encryptionIntVeD" -H "Authorization: aesiv {encrypt_pswd}" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {$token}"

The following error, which I have received:    

<html> <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head> <body> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center> </body> </html>

Comment: Please add it to the original post and add the response when using `curl -v`. `{$token}` should be `${token}`

Comment: curl -v

*Trying xx.xxx.xx.xx...
*TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sss-dev.xxx.ai (xx.xxx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
*ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/path/ca.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):

Comment: * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.domain.ai
*  start date: Feb  7 16:20:26 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 11 16:20:26 2022 GMT

Comment: * Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 401
< date: Fri, 26 Nov 2021 12:46:49 GMT
< content-type: application/problem+json
< expires: 0
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< content-security-policy-report-only: default-src 'self' https://sss-ive.domain.ai; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google.com https://static.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://fonts.com https://rs.me https://fonts.com

Comment: < x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< pragma: no-cache
< referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin
< vary: Origin
< vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< feature-policy: geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; fullscreen 'self' https://www.lm.com; payment 'none'

Comment: <
* Connection #0 to host sss-dev.domain.ai left intact
{"type":"https://www.jhipster.tech/problem-message","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"detail":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/api/generate-report","message":"error.http.401"}

Comment: please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: It's impossible to read the output like this. Please update the original question. It looks like you're getting a 401 which means unauthorized.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.